# How to know soul if attains moksha

Tags: moksha

When a very pious soul leaves the body , how can family members know whether the soul attained moksha

Comment: There is really no way to know. The practice that I follow is this. I ask God sincerely: "Oh God, please reveal to me if that be Thy Will, whether or not this soul got Moksha, I am feeling restless without knowing the Truth". And if that be God's Will, then it shall be revealed to you. But you need to have a valid reason to find out, then only it has greater possibility to reveal itself. If it is just idle curiosity, then probably nothing will be revealed immediately. :) All the best.

Comment: @Sai, have you ever got any convincing answer with your method? Has that answer come into some symbolic form or just as a thought?

Comment: @iammilind Yes of course, whenever the question is asked sincerely, the Lord responds with a most brilliant answer sir. Sometimes it is a symbolic form, sometimes it is a thought. Sometimes there is nothing :).